# Using R - Condensing multiple columns into a new column without repeating contents

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, concatenation

I'm a botanist and very beginner R user. I wonder if you can help me on finding a solution for a writing a script. I've been using R for optimizing the process of creating texts from spreadsheets. For that I use the `MonographaR` package, and I'm fine with it. The problem itself is dealing with `data.frame`. My spreadsheet (CSV file) is basically composed of columns for species, rows for characters, and their intersection cells are state of characters. I want to have a final script which allows me to get 2 or more columns combined into a new column on the original spreadsheet. When the cells have different contents the new cell content must have the individual contents separate by coma+space `", "`. When the cells have equal contents the new cell must have the same content only once, without repeating it. The scripts I've tried to write using concatenation, `cbind` etc repeated cells content, and I wasn't happy with it.

My initial CSV looks like this,

```
        cattleya.minor cattleya.maxima cattleya.pumila
colour  red            red             red
surface sharp          smooth          sharp
leaves  1              3               4
```

and I'd like to have a final result like this

```
        cattleya       cattleya.minor cattleya.maxima cattleya.pumila
colour  red            red            red             red
surface sharp, smooth  sharp          smooth          sharp
leaves  1, 3, 4        1              3               4
```

Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: Your data is not [tidy](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf), as you've got data of different types (character strings, integers) within the same columns. It would be better to transpose your data, so each column is a variable and each row is an observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @alistaire commented, start with "tidy" data and things will be much easier.

```
# Starting data (which I've called "dat")
dat
```

> ```
>         cattleya.minor cattleya.maxima cattleya.pumila
> colour             red             red             red
> surface          sharp          smooth           sharp
> leaves               1               3               4
> ```

```
library(reshape2)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

# Make data tidy
dat.tidy = dat %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var="Characteristic") %>%                # Turn rownames into a data column
  melt(id.var="Characteristic", variable.name="Species") %>%  # Reshape to "long" format
  dcast(Species ~ Characteristic)                             # Cast back to wide so that each characteristic gets its own column

dat.tidy
```

> ```
>           Species colour leaves surface
> 1  cattleya.minor    red      1   sharp
> 2 cattleya.maxima    red      3  smooth
> 3 cattleya.pumila    red      4   sharp
> ```

```
# Summarize by genus
dat.tidy %>%
  group_by(Genus=gsub("(.*)\\..*","\\1",Species)) %>%       # Collapse to genus (remove species designation)
  summarise_all(funs(paste(unique(.), collapse=", "))) %>%  # For each charactreristic, paste together each unique value for a given genus
  select(-Species)
```

> ```
>      Genus colour  leaves       surface
> 1 cattleya    red 1, 3, 4 sharp, smooth
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @allistaire & @eipi10!

Eipi10, I'm excited to be close to my objective. I had run your script exactly as you suggested and with the same dataset. It worked very fine, but it seen to have a little problem on last command block or on line `select(-Species)`. Would you check it please? R retrieves me the following:

```
> dat <- read.csv("dat.csv")
> dat
        cattleya.minor cattleya.maxima cattleya.pumila
color              red             red             red
surface          sharp          smooth           sharp
leaves               1               3               4
> 
> # Make data tidy
> dat.tidy = dat %>% 
+   rownames_to_column(var="Characteristic") %>%                # Turn     rownames into a data column
+   melt(id.var="Characteristic", variable.name="Species") %>%  # Reshape to "long" format
+   dcast(Species ~ Characteristic)                             # Cast back to wide so that each characteristic gets its own column
Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped 
> 
> dat.tidy
          Species color leaves surface
1  cattleya.minor   red      1   sharp
2 cattleya.maxima   red      3  smooth
3 cattleya.pumila   red      4   sharp
> 
> # Summarize by genus
> dat.tidy %>%
+   group_by(Genus=gsub("(.*)\\..*","\\1",Species)) %>%   # Collapse to genus (remove species designation)
+   summarise_all(funs(paste(unique(.), collapse=", ")))  # For each charactreristic, paste together each unique value for a given genus
# A tibble: 1 x 5
     Genus                                          Species color  leaves           surface
     <chr>                                            <chr> <chr>   <chr>         <chr>
1 cattleya cattleya.minor, cattleya.maxima, cattleya.pumila   red 1, 3, 4 sharp, smooth
>   select(-Species)
Error in select_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) : 
  objeto 'Species' não encontrado (my free translation: object 'Species' not found)
>
```

Comment: It's because I accidentally deleted `%>%` in the line before `select(-Species)` when I edited my answer. Sorry about that. I've fixed it now. Without the `%>%` in the previous line, R treated `select(-Species)` as a separate statement, hence the error. The `select(-Species)` is just to remove the `Species` column, but you can remove that line if you want to keep the `Species` column in the summarized output.

Comment: Fantastic solution! Thank you very much indeed.